# Only one configSections element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root configuration element

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, console-application, app-config

I am developing the console application and when I run the .exe file, I get the following error:

> `system.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException`:  Only one `<configSections>` element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root `<configuration>` element.

Here's my `App.config` file:

```xml
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <configSections>
        <section name="Reva.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <!-- ... -->
```

However, if I remove the following `startup` section, then it works fine

```xml
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Comment: In German, the error message reads "**Pro Konfigurationsdatei ist nur ein <configSections>-Element zulässig und muss, sofern vorhanden, das erste untergeordnete Element des Stamm-<configuration>-Elements sein.**" (Just in case, someone is googling this one).

Answer (score 251, accepted):

The error message itself actually details the correct fix:

> `configSections` must be the *first child** of the root element:

<sup>*emphasis added</sup>

So just move the `configSections` to the top:

```xml
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="Reva.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Today I learnt I should read the whole error message. Thanks.

Comment: @AtronSeige me too :P

Comment: I got the same error message for a windows service and the app.config doesn't even have a "<configSections>" tag in it.

Comment: Please post your config to pastebin and Link it here

Comment: As it turned out, my config was OK but the machine.config on that machine was broken. It even contained an SQLExpress/localhost connection string although no SQL was ever installed on that machine.

Comment: If you rearranged configSections as first element and you still have same error then delete everything in "Solution/bin" folder and try again.

Answer (score 2):

**The Error web.config File**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   

<configuration>    
   <connectionStrings>   
      <add name="SQLConnect" 
           connectionString="Data Source=SAHIL; Initial Catalog=Demo; Integrated Security=SSPI" 
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />   
   </connectionStrings>     

   <configSections>   
      <sectionnamesectionname="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, 
          Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" /> 
   </configSections>  

   :   
   :   
   :   
   :   
   :   
   :   
   :   
</configuration>
```

**The Error Was**

[image]

**To fix the error, I rearranged the elements and the error was fixed.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For my case:

Below `app.config` was giving run time error as

```
"ConfigurationErrorsException: Only one <configSections> element allowed per config 
file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration> element."
```

Faulty `App.config`:

```
<configuration> 
    <appSettings></appSettings>
    <configSections></configSections>   
    <startup> </startup>
    <runtime></runtime>
</configuration>
```

I just moved `<configSections></configSections>` on the top and problem resolved.

Correct `App.config`:

```
<configuration> 
    <configSections></configSections>
    <appSettings></appSettings>
    <startup> </startup>
    <runtime></runtime>
</configuration>
```